# Computing a closed cone

Tags: discrete-mathematics, optimization, algorithms, computational-geometry

Suppose we have a vector valued smooth function $F(x) = [f_1(x),f_2(x),f_3(x),...,f_n(x)]^t$ defined for $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$. Suppose we are given a rectangular domain $M = [a_1,b_1] \times [a_2,b_2] \times ... \times [a_n,b_n]$. Let K be the smallest closed cone containing $F(M)$. If we are given $F$ and $M$, how do we go about computing K?

For example, if K is generated by finitely many vectors, how do we go about computing a generating set of vectors for K? In particular, I'm interested in an algorithm that would take $F$ and $M$, and produce extremal vectors of the cone $K$.

I tried tackling this for the case n = 2. I tried optimizing f_1/f_2 in this case for f_2 positive or negative, although this feels inelegant. I'm also not sure how it would generalize to higher dimensions.

Comment: If $F$ is arbitrary, it seems to me that your question can be phrased as: how to find the smallest cone containing an arbitrary non-empty set? This might not have an explicit answer. If $F$ is "nice", e.g. continuous and/or convex, then perhaps more could be said.